# Nestedscroll view scrolls content inside it instead of expanding its layout size when touch to toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

In Coordinatorlayout inside Nestedscrollview I have RelativeLayout and inside RelativeLayout I have Textview. When Nestedscrollview touches to Toolbar bottom part it scrolls textview content instead to full Relativelayout card.

Here is my code.

```
       <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/product_bottom_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/white"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                   <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/product_img"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.imageUrl}"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:background="@color/white"/>

                   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"> 

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

           <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_60"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_7"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_7"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_7"
            android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

               <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <app.com.test.Views.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_12"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_12"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                 </RelativeLayout>

             </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

          </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try using  `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: I tried that too. but its not working

Comment: To understand you correctly. Do you want `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to start collapsing when `CustomTextView ` has enough text to scroll?

Comment: No. Right now I am getting result same like Scrollview, mens it looks like text is scrolling but I want to scroll relative layout i.e parent of textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. It's actually NestedScrollView does not scroll its child, it actually scroll content inside its child so to scroll whole layout instead of text we need to add one more parent layout like this:

```
           <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_60"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:background="@color/bg_color"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_6">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_3"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_3"
                    android:background="@drawable/card_bg">

                    <app.com.test.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/product_title_txt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_12"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_12"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12"
                        android:text=""
                     />
             </RelativeLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
          </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```